Power Bi Integration with Rest API using selected slicer values
I have a deployed ML model. I am using a Flask app to use the model and return predictions. It is a post request which input payload in this form
{
  "input_features": [
     feature_list1,
     feature_list2,
     feature_listn
    ]
}

It returns predictions in this format:
{
  "predictions": [
     prediction1,
     prediction2,
     predictionsn
    ]
}

In power Bi, I want multiple slicers in which user can a add/subract percentage of values to the current feature values. I should be able to hit the forecasting api with the adjusted values and return the predictions and visualize them
For example - I have a visualizations of around 1000 rows with 10 features. I should have 10 slicers. I can select a percentage value from slicer which should be added to the current features values. Then the forecasting API should be called adjusted values and the predictions should be visualized.
I have tried Power Query and inbuilt python code runner in power BI. Please provide a direction. Also please let me know if such scenario is even possible with Power BI

Out of the box, it is not possible. This article describes in greater detail why this is not possible. That article also describes possible custom solutions that to this challenge.
